# angularjs ng-model inside nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I don't know whether this is duplicate question or not. 
I have started exploring AngularJs. Right now I am facing this problem. 
Here is the example  [demo example](http://plnkr.co/edit/411geh0N09Y2YQU8eClQ?p=preview)

When ever I click first select drop down the below also gets updated. I know this is due to same ng-model. So, how could I generate different ng-model for two different select drop down. Please guide me as I am very new to angularjs world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the `color` object you're displaying:

```
<select ng-model="color.levelmodel" ng-options="c.id for c in levels">
    <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
</select>
```

or to the `selecteds` object like this:

```
<select ng-model="selecteds[$index].levelmodel" ng-options="c.id for c in levels">
    <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
</select>
```

Where `$index` is the current index of the `color` object inside the `colors` collection.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. If I use this ng-model="selecteds[$index].levelmodel" it gives me error "b is undefined". And if I remove levelmodel then it is working. So, you could please revisit the demo URL and use the second html with ng-model="selecteds[$index].levelmodel" you can see what type of error I am getting

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/pqBlZRZN6SvAUkWGJdtx?p=preview you need to have an array with the same amount of objects as the colors array. That's why I suggest you use the first option.

Answer (score 1):

I would bind to a level property on each color. This way instead of trying to have a random list of selected values, you have one belonging to each color, which makes much more sense.

```
$rootScope.colors = [{
      name: 'black',
      shade: 'dark',
      level: {'id': '' }
    }, {
      name: 'white',
      shade: 'light',
      level: {'id': '' }
}];

$scope.levels = [{
    "id": "1" 
}, {
    "id": "2" 
}, {
    "id": "3"
}];

<li ng-repeat="color in colors">
    <select ng-model="color.level" ng-options="c.id for c in levels">
        <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
    </select>
</li>
```